# Flutter - how to scroll all the way to the bottom of a ListView?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I use this code to scroll:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToEnd());
```

`_scrollToEnd()` method is:

```dart
_scrollController.animateTo(
  _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
  duration: const Duration(
    milliseconds: 200,
  ),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);
```

Imagine this as a normal chat screen. It scrolls to the bare bottom if the messages are in 1 line. But as soon as a message gets to 2+ lines it does not scroll **all the way** to the bottom. The more rows of a message the less it scrolls to the bottom.

This is how it looks like when i enter the chat:

[image]

But if i scroll down further this is the bottom of the chat:

[image]

I noticed there's also a case when:

1. I enter the chat.
2. It scrolls down like on the first image.
3. If i tap anywhere on the screen, it continues to scroll to the bare bottom of the listview like on the second image.

Why does this happen and how do i fix this?

Comment: can you include a list item and what are using for bottom-Widget?

Comment: Please look at the @Alwayss Bijoy answer. I think you are asking the wrong question and his answer is probably the thing you need/you'd want to use :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found a solution. None of the answers worked for me, or worked partially, but I appreciate your attempts to answer.

For me all i had to do was put

```dart
reverse: true
```

in the ListView builder and then whenever you return the message you need to return it as:

```dart
return messages[messages.length - 1 - index];
```

This is the most important part.

Answer (score 11):

what i did, use a listView and reverse true and in children use the list of map.reversed, i am giving you my code example below.

```
ListView(
          reverse: true,
          children: controller.listMessageData.reversed
           .map((e) => Container(child: Text(e.title));
```

Answer (score 10):

Just a workaround but it should work as expected. Use clamping physics in the list view. Add an extra number to the max extent

```
 _scrollController.animateTo(
 _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent+300,
 duration: const Duration(
   milliseconds: 200,
  ),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
  );
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far. It worked and now it scrolls to the bare bottom. However I noticed that there's no "drag beyond bottom" effect on ios, because of the clamping physics. Is it possible to preserve this effect?

Comment: You can change the physics to bouncephysics or a normal scrollphysics but you may see an extra bounce to the end and then it will snap in its place which may look a bit odd

Comment: Yes I noticed there's a bounce effect now. Is there a way to fix this too?

Comment: Try approximate value to add. For example if the last message is 4 lined. Add a value as 120 (30x4). That way you can use any physics of your choice and it wouldn't bounce.

Answer (score 4):

Use ScrollController for that it works smooth and simple to use

```
ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
```

Add controller to LisView like this :

```
 ListView.builder(controller: _scrollController,)
```

In your initState to scroll to bottom when navigating to this screen

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
        _scrollController.animateTo(
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        );
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it's the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Use should use the reverse property.

```
ListView.builder(
  reverse: true,
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return ListTile(title: Text(index.toString()));
  },
)
```

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem when i had to add scroll to item on its expand.
my guess is that you call animate to in the same build as when adding new elements to list, so the maximum scroll extent changes after the render of the element, and you scroll to previous one, or smth similar. what i did was to call scrollExtent few consecutive times with updated position value.

the code goes like this:

```
  static const int tickCount = 8;
  int i = 0;

  Future<void> _scrollToEnd() async {
    if (mounted && tickCount > i) {
      final ScrollPosition position = Scrollable.of(context).position;

      final double target = position.pixels +
          (position.maxScrollExtent - position.pixels) / (tickCount - i);

      position.moveTo(
        target,
        duration: duration,
        curve: Curves.linear,
      );
      await Future.delayed(duration);

      i++;
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToItem());
    }
  }
```

and on first launch reset i state:

```
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  i = 0;
                  _scrollToItem();
   });
```

code is a bit messy but i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will scroll down to the end all the time without adding any extra pixels by hand. The only downside is that you can only use `Curves.linear` as animation.

```
    Future.doWhile(() {
      if (scrollController.position.extentAfter == 0)
        return Future.value(false);
      return scrollController
          .animateTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear)
          .then((value) => true);
    });
```